# bitmap crashing when trying to convert camera-intent image to grayscale byte array

Tags: android, bitmap, grayscale, android-camera-intent

What I am trying to do, is to take a photo using a camera intent, retrieve and convert said photo to a grayscale byte array (note: I am not interested in getting a grayscale image, just need the byte data).  Then finally, apply a threshold and average all the pixels above the threshold.

The relevant snippet of code is:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);              
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


            }

    });

}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    InputStream stream = null;
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

                bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
                for(int x = 0; x < bmp.getWidth(); ++x) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < bmp.getHeight(); ++y) {
                        int index = y * bmp.getWidth() + x;
                        int R = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
                        int G = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                        int B = (pixels[index]) & 0xff;

                        double Grey = (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B);

                        if(Grey > 20) {
                            sum += Grey;
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stream != null)
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                //Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


                            double Y = sum / count;
```

The toast comment is there for testing, I used that earlier to make sure the intent was working - it was, but the path it gave was

> Content://media/external/images/media/##

(where ## is the next photo number).

I have tried this in the Eclipse emulator, and I get a RuntimeException error at where the bitmap starts.  I get a similar crash when I do a live test on an LG Optimus L3 (Android version 2.3.6).

I am convinced I have goofed up somewhere in the bitmap part of the code (and yes, I have read the developers guide and several threads here and in other places).  What is going wrong with the bitmap part?

Comment: It would help if you posted the logcat output from the crash.

Comment: the error does not come up in the logcat (this freezes and stops without errors showing), the debugger indicates that it is a RuntimeException - I would have posted the logcat if it had that information.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint right before you think the crash is happening, and evaluating the conditions of your variables?  Then stepping through and making sure it is crashing where you think it is?

Comment: Yes, thank you for that, that will be my next step - I am certain it is in the bitmap part - but just got to work out where.

Comment: If you are not catching the runtime exception, then when the debugger stops, simply continue execution and the logcat output should show up.

Comment: @TedHopp thank you, I tried that with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research throughout some questions here (and I upvoted the ones that were especially useful), and in various coding places and quite a bit of late-night-self-coding-education, I have it working now.  Below is the working code snippet:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);                
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    final String[] p1 = new String[] {
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
                    };
                    Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");
                    if ( c1.moveToFirst() ) {
                        String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/" +c1.getInt(0);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);
                        try {
                            Bitmap bm = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
                            int w = bm.getWidth();
                            int h = bm.getHeight();

                            Bitmap bmg = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, bm.getConfig());

                            for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x) {
                                for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
                                    int pixel = bm.getPixel(x, y);
                                    a = Color.alpha(pixel);
                                    r = Color.red(pixel);
                                    g = Color.green(pixel);
                                    b = Color.blue(pixel);
                                    r = g = b = (int)(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b);

                                    bmg.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(a, r, g, b));
                                    grey = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
                                    if(grey > 20) {
                                        sum += grey;
                                        count++;

                                    } 
                                    //int grey = (r + g + b) / 3;
                                }
                            }


                            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmg);
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(Y), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "newuri " + uri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } c1.close();





                //Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 


                            double Y = sum / count;
```