# What data is returned when using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm getting a bit confused from this description:

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image
>   will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small
>   sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is
>   useful for applications that only need a small image. If the
>   EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to
>   the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

With NO `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, it will return a "small sized image"?

With `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, it will return a full sized image?

"Is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field"...

On my `onActivityResult`, I was just using `Intent data` as the actual data. Am I supposed to be using `data.getExtra` or something?

Comment: +1 as this definition has never really been clear to me either.  However, I don't use the extra_output line and used a content resolver as I was after the pixel data only.

Comment: Can you expand on this? I too would only like the pixel data.

Comment: Gladly, I have expanded on this as an answer

Answer (score 4):

In the case you provide an Uri:

```
Intent action = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
action.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, myUri); 
startActivityForResult(action, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

and then you retrieve it with (after the tests on requestCode and resultCode):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myUri, options);
```

In the other case:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

and your retrieve it with:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an expansion of my comment.  This snippet of code worked well for me in giving me the pixel data - getting grayscale data and imageview is [in my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356387/bitmap-crashing-when-trying-to-convert-camera-intent-image-to-grayscale-byte-arr/17387945#17387945)

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    final String[] p1 = new String[] {
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
                    };
                    Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");
                    if ( c1.moveToFirst() ) {
                        String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/" +c1.getInt(0);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);
                        try {
                            Bitmap bm = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @EGHDK You're most welcome. I am very glad to hear that, it is a nice way to get the pixel data I have found.

Comment: @EGHDK do you need any additional help?

Comment: Nope! Thank you for your effort.