# How to get name of captured image in android onActivityResult

Tags: android, camera

how to get image name from captured image/intent data. any one suggest me. i need through intent data only

Here is my code:

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PIC_FROM_CAMERA);
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
             }
     }
```

Comment: u want send file name or bitmap?

Comment: I don't know what is your question. But make sure your requestCode is the same as PIC_FROM_CAMERA (which I think it's 2). Otherwise I know what you want to do with that Bitmap.

Comment: i need to show a image name and send it string format to server

Comment: The image name is empty because you just created a new image.

Answer (score 0):

AS from the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) you could not get any name for your image since android wont name for your file but you could get the time when the image was taken and the dimension of the image from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356387/bitmap-crashing-when-trying-to-convert-camera-intent-image-to-grayscale-byte-arr/17387945#17387945) answer You could name the image by yourself and send that bitmap.